# Python ctypes and wrapping a c++ std:wstring

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am using msvc++ and Python 2.7. I have a dll that returns a std:wstring. I am trying to wrap it in such a way that it is exposed as a c style string for calls from Python via ctypes. I obviously do not understand something about how strings are handled between the two. I have simplified this into a simple example to understand the passing mechanism. Here is what I have:

C++

```
#include <iostream>

class WideStringClass{
    public:
        const wchar_t * testString;
};


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) WideStringClass* WideStringTest()
{ 
    std::wstring testString = L"testString";
    WideStringClass* f = new WideStringClass();
    f->testString = testString.c_str();
    return f; 
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./myTest.dll')

class WideStringTestResult(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("testString", c_wchar_p)]

lib.WideStringTest.restype = POINTER(WideStringTestResult)
wst = lib.WideStringTest()
print wst.contents.testString
```

And, the output:

```
????????????????????᐀㻔
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
Changing the C++ to the following solves the problem. Of course, I think I now have a memory leak. But, that can be solved.

```
#include <iostream>

class WideStringClass{
    public:
        std::wstring testString;
        void setTestString()
        {
            this->testString = L"testString";
        }
};


class Wide_t_StringClass{
    public:
        const wchar_t * testString;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Wide_t_StringClass* WideStringTest()
{ 
    Wide_t_StringClass* wtsc = new Wide_t_StringClass();
    WideStringClass* wsc = new WideStringClass();
    wsc->setTestString();
    wtsc->testString = wsc->testString.c_str();

    return wtsc; 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big issue that is not related to Python:

`f->testString = testString.c_str();`

This is not correct, since `testString` (the `std::wstring` you declared) is a local variable, and as soon as that function returns, `testString` is gone, thus invalidates any attempt to use what `c_str()` returned.

So how do you fix this?  I'm not a Python programmer, but the way character data is usually marshalled between two differing languages is to copy characters to a buffer that was either created on the receiver's side or the sender's side (better the former than the latter).